# Ctrl+Alt+[Left/Right] not working in Ubuntu in VMWare

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard, vmware

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 as a VMWare Virtual Machine. I like to switch between my Workspaces using the `Ctrl+Alt+ArrowKeys` but it doesn't work. It works on my other system with the "Proper" install.

This is a problem with only the Left and Right keys. It works fine for Up and Down.

Comment: Are you using the left control key?

Comment: Yes. Tried the Right one as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it! It seems that VMWare uses the keys `Ctrl+Alt+Left/Right`, So there are two things you can do:

**1. Change VMWare's Default keys**
 - Go to `VMWare > Edit > Preferences > Hot Keys` and select some other combination

**2. Change Ubuntu's Shortcut** - 
Go to `System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Navigation` and select some other combination for `Switch to Workspace Left/Right`

Comment: According to the help text in the VMWare settings dialog,  you can also use `Ctrl-Alt-Space Ctrl-Alt-Left` to send `Ctrl-Alt-Left` to the guest.

Answer (score 2):

VM itself uses Ctrl+Alt for commands such as "Ctrl +_ Alt + Insert" is the same as Ctrl + Alt + Del" on your computer, you use the insert because that does the del command only in the VM where if you hit C+A+D it will bring you to the screen on your host comp not in the VM. so things like that may not work entirely running it in a VM.

Now that i read that it may be confusing so let me know if it is.

Comment: Hmmm... So it is because of VMWare. Thanks. Looking for a solution now...

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but today I was dealing with this same issue so my two cents here.What has worked in my case with VMWare Fusion 6 is:

1. Open VMWare Fusion's Preferences (CMD+,)
2. Select Keyboard & Mouse Tab
3. Uncheck "Enable Mac OS Host Keyboard Shortcuts"

This way I have native shortcuts and if I require to use Mission Control I can accomplish that holding at the same time CTRL+CMD.